# Minimum digit sum of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a prime $p$ such that

$(p^2-4)^2-117(p^2-4)+990$

has a minimum digit sum.

I do not have any idea as of how to proceed. Pls help.

Comment: This seems like quite a contrived problem...is there any context for it?   What's the smallest digit sum you have found so far?

Comment: @lulu I have found $18$ that too when $p=11$. And no, no context. This question was asked in one of the exams in math tuition.

Comment: Well, it seems obvious that the expression is always divisible by $9$ (excluding $p=3$).  Thus the only question is:  is it possible to get a digit sum of $9$?

Comment: @lulu Your comment suggests another interesting question.

Comment: How is the expression always divisible by $9$?

Comment: Just compute everything $\pmod 9$.  $9$ divides both $117$ and $990$ so you just have to argue that $p^2-4\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ which is true for every $p$ which is not a multiple of $3$, not just primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that we just need to consider the case when $p$ is a multiple of $3$ and when $p$ is not a multiple of $3$. Since $p$ is prime, $3\mid p\Leftrightarrow p=3$.

When $p=3$, the digit sum is $7$, and it is at least 9 otherwise.

We proceed to show that the digit sum is at least $9$ when $3\nmid p$.
Assume $3\nmid p$.
Let $x=p^2-4$. Considering the remainders modulo $3$, we know that $3\mid x$ since $p$ is not a multiple of 3. Thus, $9\mid (x^2-117x+990)$. But a number is divisible by $9$ iff its digit sum is divisible by $9$. This can be shown easily by induction. Since the digit sum can never be $0$ (the quadratic has no integer zeros), the digit sum will always be greater than or equal to $9$ when $3\nmid p$ and so the prime $p$ that satisfies your constraint is $\boxed{p=3}$.

Comment: Wow. Great solution.

Comment: Some problems may seem hard, but when you realize which cases to you really need to consider, they don't seem hard anymore. This is one of those problems.

Answer (score 2):

@ford jones beat me to answer this. But I am going to write it anyway.

Let $m = (p^2-4)^2-117(p^2-4)+990$.

First try $p = 3$, the digit sum is 7.

If $p \ne 3$, then $3 \nmid p$. By Fermat's Little Theorem, $p^2 \equiv 1 $(mod 3). Hence $3 \mid p^2 - 1$, $3 \mid p^2 - 4$ and $9 \mid m$. The rule for a number to be divisible by 9 is that the digit sum is multiple of 9. Hence the digit sum of $m$ will be no less than 9 for $p \ne 3$.

Hence the smallest possible digit sum is 7 with $p=3$.